# Get mean and average from only certain columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have the following dataframe.
[image: datatable]

for each time point (row) A1,A2,A3 ; A4,5,6 ; ... are 3 replicates. I would like to get the averages and standard deviation for each group of 3 per row and add it to a new df.

I have tried:

```
new_df['A1-A3_mean']=np.mean(df[['A1','A2','A3']],axis=1)
new_df['A1-A3_std']=np.std(df[['A1','A2','A3']],axis=1)
```

which works but is quite manual and time consuming. I tried using groupby('Time').agg({'mean','std'}) but not I don't know how to specify that it should always take 3 columns. Ideally the resulting column would be named A1-3_mean / A1-3_stdev

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input?

Comment: d = {'time': [1, 2, 3],'A1': [8, 2, 9], 'A2': [3, 2,5],'A3': [3, 4,5],'A4': [1, 3, 3], 'A5': [3, 8,5],'A6': [5, 2,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
N = 3

cols = list(df.drop(columns='time'))

mapper = {c: f'{cols[i//N]}-{cols[i//N+N-1]}' for i,c in enumerate(cols)}

g = df[cols].rename(columns=mapper).groupby(level=0, axis=1)

out = pd.concat({x: g.agg(x) for x in ['mean', 'std']}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       mean                 std          
      A1-A3     A2-A4     A1-A3     A2-A4
0  4.666667  3.000000  2.886751  2.000000
1  2.666667  4.333333  1.154701  3.214550
2  6.333333  4.333333  2.309401  1.154701
```

Comment: This gives me a value error:  len(index) != len(labels)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible DataFrame as input? Not an image

Comment: Hi Mozway,
`d = {'time': [1, 2, 3],'A1': [8, 2, 9], 'A2': [3, 2,5],'A3': [3, 4,5],'A4': [1, 3, 3], 'A5': [3, 8,5],'A6': [5, 2,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df`